# Create new project, R.java file not generated

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

When I create a new project in Eclipse, I automatically get errors in my MainActivity.java file when I open it, stating `R cannot be resolved to a variable`. I think it has to do with me recently updating some stuff in my SDK Manger. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try Project -> Clean...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **Project** ==> **clean and build**

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that when you create a project, the R file is not created at all?
If so, try updating the things that need to updated and try again. 
Sometimes though, right when you open a project, you have to wait for a minute for it to work properly. If this doesn't work could you also post a pic of where it shows the error?

Comment: I just added a picture of my Problems Log above!